how to send data with formset empty_form to database Django
i use inlineformset_factory to create dynamic row in django
for create or update i don't have a problem but for empty_form i get some issues
formset.empty_form.visible_fields

they don't send data for database and save it.
template code
{{formset.management_form}}
{% for fields in formset.empty_form.visible_fields %}
  <td>{{fields}}</td>
{% endfor %}

view.py
if form.is_valid():
   save_form = form.save()
   if formset.is_valid():
   formset.save()
   save_form.save()
   return redirect("/")

form.py
ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory( Invoice, InvoiceItem, form=InvoiceItemForm, extra=1,can_delete=False)

i want clicck a button add field and post this field value to database in django
